# Sending integer value through AJAX not working in PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, integer, cakephp-2.0

I am sending two integer values through AJAX

`var limit = 20;`
`var offset = 0;`

```
data = '';
data += 'limit = '+limit;
data += '&offset = '+offset;
```

Now in my `controller` (PHP) page, I used these variables to limit in a query:

```
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
$offset = $_GET['offset'];
```

And in query :

```
'limit' => $limit, //Used as LIMIT in query
'offset' => $offset, //Used as Offset in a SQL query
```

But the above query returns all the results, though I am expecting to result first 20 results. But if I write `$offset = 0` and `$limit = 20` in PHP it shows first 20 results. Why the javascript variables are not working?

Comment: try with $_POST . OR print_r($_REQUEST);

Comment: you have the `data+= '&offset'`, i think you missed `data +=limit`, the `?`

Comment: remove the spacing between the ='s

Comment: @sahbeewah, you should post your comment as an answer.